# Show that this disk is convex:

Tags: calculus

Question:

A set in the plane, which can now be thought of as a set of vectors, is called a convez set if the following holds: Whenever $ \vec u $ and $ \vec v $ belong to the set, so does $ \lambda $ $ \vec u $ + (1-$ \lambda $)$ \vec v $ for any scalar $ \lambda $ between 0 and 1. Consider the disk of radius "a" centered at the point . Show that this disk is convex.

I showed that $ \lambda $ $ \vec u $ + (1-$ \lambda $)$ \vec v $ is less than or equal to a

and that <$x_0$,$y_0$> is <= a.

Comment: convez $\mapsto$ convex $\;$

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the inequality

$$|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$$

Answer (score 0):

If your disc's center is the origin and it's radius $a$, then $x$ belongs to the disc iff $\|x\|^2\leq a^2$.  Let $u$ and $v$ belong to the disc and let $0\leq\lambda\leq1$.  Then
$$\|\lambda u+(1-\lambda)v\|^2=\lambda^2\|u\|^2+2\lambda(1-\lambda)\langle u,v\rangle+(1-\lambda)^2\|v\|^2.$$
Now use that $\|u\|^2\leq a^2$, $\|v\|^2\leq a^2$ and $\langle u,v\rangle\leq\|u\|\cdot\|v\|$ and your're done.